# Adding unit test to a legacy Scala project in IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I have a legacy Scala project to work with using maven as build tool.

Initially there is core code only under folder structure src/main/scala/ with package x.y.z and a file Main.scala with code as:

```
object Main {
 def cube(x: Int) = {
   x * x * x
 }
}
```

There are no tests for the code. So I manually added a folder structure as test/scala under src.
Then I copied the package as for core code, ie x.y.z and added MainTest.scala with test code as:

```
class MainTest extends FunSuite {

   test("Main.cube") {
     assert(Main.cube(3) === 27)
   }

 }
```

Running test gives error as:

> Error:(8, 12) not found: value Main
>
> assert(Main.cube(3) === 27)

Why do I get this error?

Comment: Does the test file import `x.y.z.Main`, or is it declared to be in the same package?

Comment: I tried both, but same issue.

Comment: Can you edit your sample code to include the package declarations and relevant imports?

Answer (score 0):

For below project structure MainTest.scala and Main.scala are in the same package x.y.z therefore no package import is required, However MainTempTest.scala and Main.scala are in different package therefore an explicit import has to be done import x.y.z.Main

```
src
  -main
    --scala
      ---x.y.z
        ----Main.scala
  -test
    --scala
      ---MainTempTest.scala
      ---x.y.z
        ----MainTest.scala
```